# Duplicate values in array cause a undefined to appear

Tags: javascript, arrays

I was making a js code that gets items from an array. One problem: items with same value return undefined or disappear. I tried many different things but nothing is working. Here is a jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/76e40vqg/5/

```
var data =
    [{"image":"link1","name":"Name1","address":"Address1","rate":"4.4"},
    {"image":"link2","name":"Name2","address":"Address2","rate":"3.3"},
    {"image":"link3","name":"Name3","address":"Address3","rate":"3.3"}
];

var restoName = [];
for(i = 0; i < data.length; i++){    
    if(restoName.indexOf(data[i].name) === -1){
        restoName.push(data[i].name);        
    }        
}

var restoAddress = [];
for(i = 0; i < data.length; i++){    
    if(restoAddress.indexOf(data[i].address) === -1){
        restoAddress.push(data[i].address);        
    }        
}

var restoRate = [];
for(i = 0; i < data.length; i++){    
    if(restoRate.indexOf(data[i].rate) === -1){
        restoRate.push(data[i].rate);        
    }        
}

var restoImage = [];
for(i = 0; i < data.length; i++){    
    if(restoImage.indexOf(data[i].image) === -1){
        restoImage.push(data[i].image);
    }        
}

for(i = 0; i < restoName.length; i++){
document.getElementById('output').innerHTML += "Image : <a href='" + restoImage[i] + "'><div class='thumb' style='background-image:" + 'url("' + restoImage[i] + '");' + "'></div></a><br>" + "Name : " + restoName[i] + "<br>" + "Address : " + restoAddress[i] + "<br>" + "Rate : " + restoRate[i] + "<br>" + "Index" + "<br><hr>";
  }
```

Comment: you posted input array, could you post the expected output

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This piece of code in the JS Fiddle:

```
if (restoRate.indexOf(data[i].rate) === -1)
{
    restoRate.push(data[i].rate);
}
```

Says literally, if there is not the value `3.3`, push it into `restoRate`. Otherwise, don't push it.

In other words, the second `3.3` is not pushed because this is what you want (have implemented) and thus for index `3` there is no value and you get `undefined`.

---

**EDIT**: Proposed solution which probably is insufficient

To fix it, don't check for uniqueness, just like this (without the surrounding `if()`):

```
restoRate.push(data[i].rate);
```

It is not clear if this is what you need further down your code, so probably you need to rethink some parts of your code. In this we cannot help you, or better it calls for another, precise question with the other code.

---

**EDIT 2**: Better solution with uniqueness

You added a check for uniqueness, so you probably still need it. The first step you must do is decide what is the *key*. You may want to add an `id` because people may have the same name but still be different people, if you get what I mean:

```
{"id": 45, "image":"link1","name":"Name1","address":"Address1","rate":"4.4"},
{"id": 46, "image":"link2","name":"Name1","address":"Address2","rate":"4.1"}
```

This example shows two entries with the same name but two completely different cases. The `id` is the actual *key* you use to distinguish entries.

If you do this, you must check for the `id`'s uniqueness:

```
if (restoId.indexOf(data[i].id) === -1) // this id is new
{
    restoId.push(data[i].id);
    restoImage.push(data[i].image);
    restoName.push(data[i].name);
    restoAddress.push(data[i].address);
    restoRate.push(data[i].rate);
}
```

If you can't add an `id` you must probably go with the `name`, like this:

```
if (restoName.indexOf(data[i].name) === -1) // this id is new
{
    restoImage.push(data[i].image);
    restoName.push(data[i].name);
    restoAddress.push(data[i].address);
    restoRate.push(data[i].rate);
}
```

This may be, or not be what you need. Nobody can tell without actual data and full code.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your explanation. How can I fix that?

Comment: Look, I've added a solution but it is probably insufficient.

Comment: sure he can. You can push everything you like into an array. he just has to remove the surrounding ifs.

Comment: Sorry i removed my comment. yeah he can push

Comment: Cool, now it works. Will I encounter more problems if I use this?

Comment: Yes, because you need to check for uniqueness apparently. I'll add another solution shortly. It's just a matter of writing fast :)

Comment: There you go. I've added a complete solution.

Comment: The 1st one is the one I need with my project

Comment: No I don't want to check for uniqueness, it's a wrong code placed by error. Anyways thank you so much

Comment: Cool! That's even better :)

Answer (score 1):

I see you are purposefully avoiding duplicates by placing

`if(restoRate.indexOf(data[i].rate) === -1)`

If you remove this check there would be no issues displaying duplicate code.

I also thing you can add all of them together and put a check to avoid duplicate names. Like shown below :

```
 if(restoName.indexOf(data[i].name) === -1){
    restoName.push(data[i].name); 
    restoAddress.push(data[i].address);
    restoRate.push(data[i].rate);
    restoImage.push(data[i].image);
}
```

[Please check this jsfiddle for implementation](https://jsfiddle.net/VarunG/76e40vqg/9/)

Comment: Does this answer your question? Because there is no specific output mentioned here.

Comment: Not really, because there is a if. But other than that, for the size of the script, it is better

Answer (score 0):

Your code working as you have written `restoRate.indexOf(data[i].rate) === -1`
means your array does not contain any values. For example

```
var array = [2, 9, 9];
array.indexOf(2);     // 0
array.indexOf(7);     // -1
array.indexOf(9, 2);  // 2
array.indexOf(2, -1); // -1
array.indexOf(2, -3); // 0
```

Please check the [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) concept in javascript

Answer (score 0):

You are not inserting duplicate value into your rate array  `if(restoRate.indexOf(data[i].rate) === -1)`, that is way its saying undefined in the display.

Moreover try to implement everything without making 4 new for loops. I think it can be done without creating any new array variables and iterating only the original array. The Big O will be less and performance will be good.

```
var restoRate = [];
for(i = 0; i < data.length; i++){    
    if(restoRate.indexOf(data[i].rate) === -1){
        restoRate.push(data[i].rate);        
    }        
}
```